# NIntegrate within NMinimize - how to optimize the code?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

How I can optimize these numerical calculations? Most annoying is encountering instabilities (numerical errors).

I have a predefined function:

```
U1 = -0.1224744871391589` q0 ((Cos[θ] Sin[β]
Sin[γ] + 
       Cos[k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[γ] Sin[α] + 
          Cos[α] Cos[β] Sin[γ]) Sin[θ] - 
(Cos[α] Cos[γ] - 
          Cos[β] Sin[α] Sin[γ]) Sin[θ] Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])])^2 - (Cos[θ] (-Cos[β] 
Sin[π/8] - Cos[π/8] Cos[γ] Sin[β]) + 
       Cos[k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β] - 
          Cos[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - 
(-Sin[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] - 
          Cos[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2) - 
  q0 (-(1/2) + 
     3/2 (Cos[θ] (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
           Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β]) + 
        Cos[k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (Cos[π/
             8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
              Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - (-Cos[
π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
              Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
          k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2) - 
  0.14142135623730953` q2 (-(1/
      2) + (Cos[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Cos[γ] - 
          Cos[β] Sin[α] Sin[γ]) + (Cos[γ] 
Sin[α] + Cos[α] Cos[β] Sin[γ]) Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2 - 
     1/2 (Cos[θ] (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
           Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β]) + 
        Cos[k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (Cos[π/
             8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
              Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - (-Cos[
π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
              Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
          k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/
               8] Sin[β])])^2 + (Cos[θ] Cos[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β] - 
          Cos[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) - 
       Cos[θ] (-Sin[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] - 
          Cos[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] + (-Cos[β] Sin[π/8] - 
          Cos[π/
            8] Cos[γ] Sin[β]) (-Cos[
             k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
                Cos[γ] Sin[π/
                  8] Sin[β])]^2 Sin[θ] - 
          Sin[θ] Sin[
            k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
               Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])]^2))^2) - 
  1/2 Sqrt[3]
    q2 ((Cos[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (-Cos[π/
             8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) + (Cos[π/
            8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])])^2 - (Cos[θ] Cos[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (Cos[π/
            8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) - 
       Cos[θ] (-Cos[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] + (-Cos[π/
             8] Cos[β] + 
          Cos[γ] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β]) (-Cos[
             k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
                Cos[γ] Sin[π/
                  8] Sin[β])]^2 Sin[θ] - 
          Sin[θ] Sin[
            k (-Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
               Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])]^2))^2) - 
  0.1224744871391589` q0 ((Cos[θ] Sin[β] Sin[γ] + 
       Cos[k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[γ] Sin[α] + 
          Cos[α] Cos[β] Sin[γ]) Sin[θ] - 
(Cos[α] Cos[γ] - 
          Cos[β] Sin[α] Sin[γ]) Sin[θ] Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])])^2 - (Cos[θ] (-Cos[β] 
Sin[π/8] + Cos[π/8] Cos[γ] Sin[β]) + 
       Cos[k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β] + 
          Cos[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - 
(-Sin[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Cos[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2) - 
  q0 (-(1/2) + 
     3/2 (Cos[θ] (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
           Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β]) + 
        Cos[k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (-Cos[π/
              8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 

              Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - 
(Cos[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
              Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
          k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2) - 
  0.14142135623730953` q2 (-(1/
      2) + (Cos[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Cos[γ] - 
          Cos[β] Sin[α] Sin[γ]) + (Cos[γ] 
Sin[α] + Cos[α] Cos[β] Sin[γ]) Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])])^2 - 
     1/2 (Cos[θ] (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
           Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β]) + 
        Cos[k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (-Cos[π/
              8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
              Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] - 
(Cos[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
           Sin[π/
             8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
              Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[θ] Sin[
          k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
             Cos[γ] Sin[π/
               8] Sin[β])])^2 + (Cos[θ] Cos[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] (Cos[α] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β] + 
          Cos[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) - 
       Cos[θ] (-Sin[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Cos[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])] + (-Cos[β] Sin[π/8] + 
          Cos[π/
            8] Cos[γ] Sin[β]) (-Cos[
             k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
                Cos[γ] Sin[π/
                  8] Sin[β])]^2 Sin[θ] - 
          Sin[θ] Sin[
            k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
               Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])]^2))^2) - 
  1/2 Sqrt[3]
    q2 ((Cos[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (Cos[π/
            8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) + (-Cos[π/
             8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/
              8] Sin[β])])^2 - (Cos[θ] Cos[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] (-Cos[π/
             8] Cos[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (Cos[α] Cos[β] Cos[γ] - 
             Sin[α] Sin[γ])) - 
       Cos[θ] (Cos[π/8] Sin[α] Sin[β] + 
          Sin[π/
            8] (-Cos[β] Cos[γ] Sin[α] - 
             Cos[α] Sin[γ])) Sin[
         k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
            Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])] + (Cos[π/
            8] Cos[β] + 

          Cos[γ] Sin[π/
            8] Sin[β]) (-Cos[
             k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
                Cos[γ] Sin[π/
                  8] Sin[β])]^2 Sin[θ] - 
          Sin[θ] Sin[
            k (Cos[π/8] Cos[β] + 
               Cos[γ] Sin[π/8] Sin[β])]^2))^2)
```

which later is needed to define a function:

```
z[q0_, q2_, θ_, k_, t_] := 
 NIntegrate[
   Exp[-U1/t]*Sin[β], {α, 0, 2 π}, {β, 
    0, π}, {γ, 0, 2 π}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
   Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, 
     Method -> {GaussKronrodRule}} ]/(8 π^2)
```

Then I have to calculate as follows:

```
ParallelTable[
 NMinimize[{(q0)^2 + (q2)^2 - (t)*
     Log[z[q0, q2, θ, ϕ, (t)]], 0 <= q0 <= 1, 
   0 <= q2 <= Sqrt[3], 0 <= θ < π/4, k >= 0}, {q0, 
   q2, θ, k}], {t, 0.1, 0.65, 0.05}]
```

Comment: Within NMinize there is an ϕ, probably you need k. Then define z as follows: z[q0_?NumericQ, q2_?NumericQ, θ_?NumericQ,k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ]

Comment: Your first block of code produces three `Out` lines, but only the first is assigned to a variable, `U1`.  This suggests that either you copied some extraneous code into the question, or there are misplaced <Return>s in your code.